# How to tell if element in HTML is complete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I know how many elements ( for ex : `<p>..`) is complete(ends with `</p>`) in the HTML using JavaScript?

For instance, in HTML code:

```
<input  value='value 1' />
<input  value='value 2' >
<input  value='value 3' />
<input  value='value 1' />
```

What code in JavaScript will give me that there are 3 elements with input tag?

Comment: `<p>` has an optional closing tag.  It might be worth pointing out that you can have complete and valid html that has unclosed `<p>` tags.

Comment: And there are 4 tags in your html example.  Three have a `/` at the end, but that's not significant in html5.

Comment: You can't. Invalid HTML is either not added to the DOM or is reconfigured so that it appears valid in the DOM. For instance, code like `<span><b>blah</span></b>` is invalid, but will likely be parsed into the DOM as an HTMLSpanElement parent with an HTMLElement child with a Node child of type TEXT_NODE.

Comment: What if the page is loading its content through javascript and I inject my javascript code that gets the number of (*) tags with their inner Html within fixed intervals which may give me a unclosed tags? Or will it never give me unclosed tags?

Comment: By the time you get access to the document through the DOM api, there is no such thing as an unclosed tag.  That's a concept that exists in the html source.  After the browser parses that html source, the distinction is gone.

Comment: Ohh.. Now I get it, thanks alot recursive,Mike.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the following markup:

```
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
```

And use the following jquery script:

```
console.log($('input').length);
```

The console will output `3`

[Demo](http://codepen.io/obliviga/pen/dvMXNX?editors=1010)

Comment: thats the problem, the Output of your commented code must be 0 as none of the "input" tag was closed. How to know, how many "input" tags were closed

Comment: It is invalid to close `<input>` tags.  The concept of "closing" an `<input>` tag has no basis in the html specification.

Comment: its not input tag lets its something other that can be closed ( div )

Comment: The DOM api exposes a model of the document as it exists after the html parser has made its best guess about what was meant by invalid markup.  If you have tags that are required to be closed, but are not, there's no way to detect that from the DOM api.  You'd need to be running in a process which has direct access to the un-parsed html source.  Maybe you could use an XHR to request `window.location` and parse the html in javascript?  Maybe possible, but not advisable.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Ralphs answer, if you'd like to use vanilla JS it can be done so via

```
document.querySelectorAll('input').length;
```

Comment: I think It will output (3) of the Ralph's Answer, which is not what I want

Comment: You're asking in your question "What code in JavaScript will give me that there are 3 elements with input tag?" Please clarify what you want, with what is actually written in your post.

Comment: @CameronRasto not sure I understand your question then. Originally you are asking to print out all of the input tags, which in your initial question and example would output 4. Are you instead asking to output the number of unique input tags (i.e. the two inputs with value='1' would only count 1??)

Comment: i got my answer in my question replies. Thanks alot Addison and Ralph